# SASS - Avoid importing mixins repeatedly in partials

Tags: import, sass, mixins, partial

Sorry if this has been asked already, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I'm trying to keep my SASS files organised, and as such am using a load of partials to separate concerns... `_mixins.scss`. `_header.scss`, `_footer.scss`, `_sidebar`, etc.

I then have my `styles.scss` file, which looks a little like:

```
@import 'mixins'
@import 'header'
@import 'footer'
@import 'sidebar'
```

The issue I'm facing is if I have a mixin in my `_mixins.scss` partial, let's say, `@function size() {}`, and I want to use it in `_header.scss`, I'm unable to (libsass throws an error - `Error: no mixin named size`).

In my mind it should simply be importing each partial into `styles.scss`, and as it gets the mixins partial before the call is made to the `@include size()` function, then it should know what to do. This is obviously not the case though...

So...

**Is there any way to save an `@import 'mixins'` being put at the top of each of my other partials**?

As I use more than one library, this could get messy quickly if I need to maintain a dozen or so 'content-styling' partials with every library.

---

Oh, and if it helps I'm using gulp to build it... The relevent task is:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  var plugins = [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['> 0%']
    })
  ];
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: sassPaths,
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(postcss(plugins))
      .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup... In my real world case I neglected the `_` before the 'content-styles' filename, i.e., `_header.scss`... I feel like a dope!

Well at least I learnt what a partial actually does.

Thanks to anyone who was answering this. :)

Answer (score 0):

This case `"Error: no mixin named size"` seems to be associated with scoping problems.

Apparently, when you `@include` a mixin which its source is not located in the actual file scope Sass will throw that error (or something like `"undefined mixin"`).

I would recommend to write your mixins into a partial file `_mixins.scss` then all you need to do is import it into `styles.scss` at the very top.

**Tests were made using Dart Sass

Hope this was helpful